# Products aren't displaying, showing products undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router-dom

Integrated redux now products aren't showing anymore. I tried adding a condition like `"{products && products.map((product) => ..")`. A blank page disappears but still no products. The error disappears as well though. In the redux devTools I get:

```
{
  type: 'PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS',
  payload: [
    {
      _id: 1,
      name: 'IPhone 11 Pro 256GB memory',
      image: '/images/phone.jpg',
      brand: 'Apple',
      category: 'Electronics',
      description: 'Bluetooth technology lets you connect it with compatible devices wirelessly High-Quality AAC audio offers immense experience Built-in microphone allows you take calls while working',
      rating: '4.00',
      numReviews: 8,
      price: '599.99',
      countInStock: 7,
      created: '2022-11-14T18:29:17.417487Z',
      user: 1
    },
  ]
}
```

store.js:

```
import {
  legacy_createStore as createStore,
  combineReducers,
  applyMiddleware,
} from "redux";
//import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension";
import {
  productListReducers,
  productDetailsReducers,
} from "./reducers/ProductReducers";

const reducer = combineReducers({
  productList: productListReducers,
  productDetails: productDetailsReducers,
});

const initialState = {};
const middleware = [thunk];
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
);

export default store;
```

app.js:

```
import "./App.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Container } from "react-bootstrap";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import HomeScreen from "./components/screens/HomeScreen";
import ProductScreen from "./components/screens/ProductScreen";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Header />
      <main className="my-3">
        <Container>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<HomeScreen />} />
            <Route path="/product/:id" element={<ProductScreen />} />
          </Routes>
        </Container>
      </main>
      <Footer />
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

HomeScreen.js:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
//import products from "../../products";
import { Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import Product from "../Product";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { listProducts } from "../../actions/ProductAction";
import Message from "../Message";
import Loader from "../Loader";

function HomeScreen() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const productList = useSelector((state) => state.productList);
  const { error, loading, products } = productList;
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(listProducts());
  }, [dispatch]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className="text-center">Latest Products</h1>
      {loading ? (
        <Loader />
      ) : error ? (
        <Message variant="danger">{error}</Message>
      ) : (
        <Row>
          {products &&
            products.map((product) => (
              <Col key={product._id} sm={12} md={6} lg={4} xl={3}>
                {/* <h3>{product.name}</h3> */}
                <Product product={product} />
              </Col>
            ))}
        </Row>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default HomeScreen;
```

ProductScreen.js:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { Row, Col, Image, ListGroup, Button, Card } from "react-bootstrap";
//import products from "../../products";
import Rating from "../Rating";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import Message from "../Message";
import Loader from "../Loader";
import { listProductDetails } from "../../actions/ProductAction";
import { productDetailsReducers } from "../../reducers/ProductReducers";

function ProductScreen() {
  const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(1);
  const { id } = useParams();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const productDetails = useSelector((state) => state.productDetails);
  const { loading, error, product } = productDetails;

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchProduct() {
      if (id) {
        dispatch(listProductDetails(id));
      }
    }
    fetchProduct();
  }, [dispatch, id]);
  return (
    <div>
      <Link to="/" className="btn btn-dark my-3">
        Go Back
      </Link>
      {loading ? (
        <Loader />
      ) : error ? (
        <Message variant="danger">{error}</Message>
      ) : (
        <Row>
          <Col md={6}>
            <Image
              className="imgCustom"
              src={product.image}
              alt={product.name}
            ></Image>
          </Col>
          <Col md={3}>
            <ListGroup variant="flush">
              <ListGroup.Item>
                <h3>{product.name}</h3>
              </ListGroup.Item>
              <ListGroup.Item>
                <Rating
                  value={product.rating}
                  text={`${product.numReviews} reviews`}
                  color={"f8e825"}
                />
              </ListGroup.Item>
              <ListGroup.Item>Price : ${product.price}</ListGroup.Item>

              <ListGroup.Item>
                Description: ${product.description}
              </ListGroup.Item>
            </ListGroup>
          </Col>

          <Col md={3}>
            <Card>
              <ListGroup variant="flush">
                <ListGroup.Item>
                  <Row>
                    <Col>Price : </Col>
                    <Col>
                      <strong>$ {product.price}</strong>
                    </Col>
                  </Row>
                </ListGroup.Item>

                <ListGroup.Item>
                  <Row>
                    <Col>Status : </Col>
                    <Col>
                      {product.countInStock > 0 ? "In Stock" : "Out of Stock"}
                    </Col>
                  </Row>
                </ListGroup.Item>

                <ListGroup.Item>
                  <Button
                    className="btn-block"
                    disabled={product.countInStock === 0}
                    type="button"
                  >
                    Add to Cart
                  </Button>
                </ListGroup.Item>
              </ListGroup>
            </Card>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default ProductScreen;
```

ProductAction.js:

```
import axios from "axios";
import {
  PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST,
  PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS,
  PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL,
  PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST,
  PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS,
  PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL,
} from "../constants/ProductConstants";

export const listProducts = () => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST });

    const { data } = await axios.get("/api/products/");

    dispatch({
      type: PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS,
      payload: data,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL,
      payload:
        error.response && error.response.data.detail
          ? error.response.data.detail
          : error.message,
    });
  }
};

export const listProductDetails = (id) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST });

    const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/products${id}`);

    dispatch({
      type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS,
      payload: data,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL,
      payload:
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message,
    });
  }
};
```

ProductReducers.js:

```
import {
  PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST,
  PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS,
  PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL,
  PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST,
  PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS,
  PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL,
} from "../constants/ProductConstants";

export const productListReducers = (state = { products: [] }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST:
      return { loading: true, product: [] };
    case PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS:
      return { loading: false, product: [action.payload] };
    case PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL:
      return { loading: true, product: [action.payload] };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export const productDetailsReducers = (state = {product:{ reviews: [] }}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST:
      return { loading: true, ...state };
    case PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS:
      return { loading: false, product: [action.payload] };
    case PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL:
      return { loading: true, product: [action.payload] };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

It appears the `HomeScreen` component is selecting out a `products` property that doesn't exist in the redux store state slice after the state is updated at least once.

HomeScreen

```
function HomeScreen() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const productList = useSelector((state) => state.productList);
  const { error, loading, products } = productList; // <-- products
```

Redux store's combined reducers

```
const reducer = combineReducers({
  productList: productListReducers,
  productDetails: productDetailsReducers,
});
```

productListReducers

None of the reducer cases here maintain the `products` array state invariant, they each change/return a `product` property.

```
export const productListReducers = (state = { products: [] }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST:
      return { loading: true, product: [] };
    case PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS:
      return {
        loading: false,
        product: [action.payload] // <-- product, not products
      };
    case PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL:
      return { loading: true, product: [action.payload] };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Additionally the `PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS` action appears to return a payload that ***is*** a products array.

```
{
  type: 'PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS',
  payload: [
    {
      _id: 1,
      name: 'IPhone 11 Pro 256GB memory',
      image: '/images/phone.jpg',
      brand: 'Apple',
      category: 'Electronics',
      description: 'Bluetooth technology lets you connect it with compatible devices wirelessly High-Quality AAC audio offers immense experience Built-in microphone allows you take calls while working',
      rating: '4.00',
      numReviews: 8,
      price: '599.99',
      countInStock: 7,
      created: '2022-11-14T18:29:17.417487Z',
      user: 1
    },
  ]
}
```

`return { loading: false, product: [action.payload] };` would result in nesting an array within an array, which is likely not what was intended.

## Solution

Maintain the `products` property state invariant and set the `products` state to be the value of the `action.payload`. You very also likely want to clear the `products` array and set some error state in the case of failure.

```
export const productListReducers = (state = { products: [] }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST:
      return { loading: true, products: [] };

    case PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS:
      return { loading: false, products: action.payload };

    case PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL:
      return {
        loading: false,        // <-- clear loading state
        products: [],          // <-- empty products array
        error: action.payload, // <-- set error state
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export const productDetailsReducers = (
  state = {
    loading: false,
    product: {
      reviews: []
    }
  },
  action
) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST:
      return { ...state, loading: true };

    case PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        product: {
          ...state.product,
          reviews: action.payload,
        }
      };

    case PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        product: {
          ...state.product,
          reviews: [],
        },
        error: action.payload,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: Oh wow thank you dear sit! Been struggling with it all day! And I do the same thing for ProductScreen? "productDetailsReducers" @dre-reese

Comment: @Khaled Aye, well I suppose there's a similar, but different, invariant issue there in `productDetailsReducers`. The `product` state there is initially an object with a `reviews` property that is an array, but the reducer cases change `product` to be an array. The fix will be similar.

Comment: I tried solving it but no luck there, could update the answer with a solution for that as well please? @dre-reese

Comment: @Khaled Ok, took a stab at a suggested update for that other reducer function.

Comment: Still gives me "Request failed with status code 404" :( @drew-reese

Comment: @Khaled Oh, that seems like an error with some API request. I don't think it's related to a Redux reducer function. You might want to post this as a new post on SO since it seems to be a bit off-topic for this post. If you do create a new post feel free to ping me here with a link to it and I can take a look when available.

Comment: You were right I fixed the api issue, it was a typo but everything rendered only with previous function, didn't work how you updated it for some reason.. Thank you! @drew-reese